# How do I numerically organise a variable labeller in a facet_wrap graph?

Tags: r

I have 60 faceted graphs and renamed the values in a column that is also called Pt. Because there are multiple rows with "1054law", if I just do it individually and try to mutate it, it tells me there are too many mismatches.

```
Pt <- c("1054law" = "Pt 01",
                     "1066" = "Pt 02",
                     "1083" = "Pt 03")

variable_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  return(Pt[value])
}

g01<- ggplot(VT6s, aes(x=Norm_SBP_Mean, y=log(Laser1_Magic), col=Period, shape=Symptoms))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(labels=percent)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(4,21,16))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1.1))+
  facet_wrap(~Pt, labeller = variable_labeller)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=log(2), col="black")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=log(5), col="black")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.9, col="green", linetype="dashed")+
  scale_color_manual("Rate", values=c("#FFEE89" ,"#FFC689", "#FFA700", "#FF5800", "#FF0000", "#D40000", "#930000"))+
  theme_light()
```

but when I do this, although it is labelled correctly, it comes up in the order of the original column, rather than the order of the renamed variable or numerical order.

I've renamed my variable to Pt_n and changed it in the the facet wrap to:

```
Pt_n <- c("1054law" = "Pt 01",
                     "1066" = "Pt 02",
                     "1083" = "Pt 03")

variable_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  return(Pt_n[value])
}
facet_wrap(~Pt_n, labeller = variable_labeller)
```

And it tells me Pt_n is not present in the layers so I can't do that.

The I tried cbind and order/sort/arrange/mixedsort and still haven't been able to organise it properly.

Would be grateful for any input here...

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format?  Edit your post to include `dput(VT6s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.

```
mutate(Pt_n = recode(Pt, "1054law" = "Pt 01",
                     "1066" = "Pt 02",
                     "1083" = "Pt 03"))
```

And then took out the variable labeller

```
g01<- ggplot(VT6s, aes(x=Norm_SBP_Mean, y=log(Laser1_Magic), col=Period, shape=Symptoms))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(labels=percent)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(4,21,16))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1.1))+
  facet_wrap(~Pt_n)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=log(2), col="black")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=log(5), col="black")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.9, col="green", linetype="dashed")+
  scale_color_manual("Rate", values=c("#FFEE89" ,"#FFC689", "#FFA700", "#FF5800", "#FF0000", "#D40000", "#930000"))+
  theme_light()
```

I'm sure there's a more erm..."code-efficient" way of doing this as I had to do this for 54 entries. But this at least did the trick.